# Coq dependent types

Tags: coq, dependent-type

I am new to Coq and need some help with some of trivial examples to get me started. In particular I am interested in defining some operations of vectors (fixed size lists) using dependent types. I started with Vector package and trying to implement some additional  functions. For example I am having difficulty implementing trivial 'take' and 'drop' functions, which take or drop first 'p' elements from the list.

```
Require Import Vector.

Fixpoint take {A} {n} (p:nat) (a: t A n) : p<=n -> t A p := 
   match a return ( p<=n -> t A p) with
     | cons A v (S m) => cons (hd v) (take m (tl v)) m
     | nil => fun pf => a
   end.
```

The error (in case of `nil`) is:

```
The term "a" has type "t A n" while it is expected to have type "t A p".
```

Could somebody help me with some starting points? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question, but there's a good book that I bought a while back when I was thinking about getting serious about learning Coq.  It's called, "Interactive Theorem Proving and Development."  Also, this question might be better suited for cs.se, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @PhilipWhite This isn't any more on-topic on [cs.se] than here, as it's strictly about programming in Coq, and not about understanding the theoretical underpinnings. This question would be fine on [so].

Comment: @krokodil -- this question is off-topic here, as it is not about cs theory. I can migrate your question stack overflow if you'd like.  Otherwise, this question will be closed soon as off topic.

Comment: Sorry for using wrong forum. Feel free to move to stack overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand your approach. You're always returning a non-empty vector when the argument is a non-empty vector, but `take` must return `nil` when `p=0` regardless of the vector.

Here's one approach to building `take`. Rather than using the hypothesis `p <= n`, I express the length of the argument `n` as a sum of the number `p` of elements to take and the number of trailing elements `m`, which is possible iff `p <= n`. This allows for an easier recursive definition, because `(S p') + m` is structurally equal to `S (p' + m)`. Note that the discrimination is on the number of elements to take: return `nil` if taking 0, return `cons head new_tail` otherwise.

This version of the `take` function has the desired computational behavior, so all that's left is to define one with the desired proof content. I use the `Program` feature to do this conveniently: fill in the computational content (trivial, I just need to say that I want to use `m = n - p`), then complete the proof obligations (which are simple arithmetic).

```
Require Import Arith.
Require Import Vector.

Fixpoint take_plus {A} {m} (p:nat) : t A (p+m) -> t A p := 
   match p return t A (p+m) -> t A p with
     | 0 => fun a => nil _
     | S p' => fun a => cons A (hd a) _ (take_plus p' (tl a))
   end.
Program Definition take A n p (a : t A n) (H : p <= n) : t A p :=
          take_plus (m := n - p) p a.
Solve Obligations using auto with arith.
```

---

For your `newdrop : forall A n p, t A n -> p <= n -> t A (n-p)`, the following approach works. You need to help Coq by telling it what `p` and `n` become in the recursive call.

```
Program Fixpoint newdrop  {A} {n} p : t A n -> p <= n -> t A (n-p) :=
   match p return t A n -> p <= n -> t A (n-p) with
     | 0 => fun a H => a
     | S p' => fun a H => newdrop p' (tl a) (_ : p' <= n - 1)
   end.
Next Obligation.
omega.
Qed.
Next Obligation.
omega.
Qed.
Next Obligation.
omega.
Qed.
Next Obligation.
omega.
Qed.
```

I don't know why `Solve Obligations using omega.` doesn't work but solving each obligation individually works.

Comment: what does _ argument to `nil` means here? This constructor does not take any arguments. I do not fully understand how this part works.

Comment: @krokodil The constructor `nil` takes the type of elements (`A`) as an argument. I let Coq infer it. If you `Set Implicit Arguments`, you won't need (or be able to) specify it.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles! One more question, if I may. Following the pattern shown above I was able to define `drop` function. However I wanted to try to have slightly different definition and attempted: http://pastebin.com/MauLg8jN This fails because types (t A n) and (t A (n-0)) do not match. If there is a way to solve that perhaps by proving a lemma and refering to it? I want to learn generic technique of plugging lemmas into such definitions.

Comment: @krokodil See my edit. You had a simple type error with the argument `a` expressed twice in the type. You need to put `H` in the dependent matching as well. There are proof obligations, because you need to prove some arithmetic equalities like `n = n - 0`. The whole point of `Program` is to help with this: you can define the computational content in a clean way and prove the remaining obligations afterwards.

Comment: Thanks again! It looks like there are quite some tricks for me to learn. Any books you could recommend? I was reading http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/ but it perhaps I need something even more fundamental to start with? One more observation: I am still unsure why you changed type of `newdrop` the way you did. I do not understand why column is after `p`.

Comment: @krokodil The `match …`  term has the type `t A n -> p <= n -> t A (n-p)`: it takes the vector and the arithmetic hypothesis as arguments. I haven't looked at Coq books in a few years; I read the Coq'Art book soon after it came out but there might be something better and more up-to-date now.